# Error: A value of type 'TimeOfDay' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'DateTime'

Tags: flutter, dart, datetimepicker

I am trying to get time from time picker in this format `Thrusday at 10:00pm until`. I did found a solution on google to use `intl` library from dart to format date to display in `10:00pm` format. but here the problem is whenever i try to put `DataTime.now()` to get `time picker` I get this error.

> Error: A value of type 'TimeOfDay' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'DateTime'.

Here is my code

```
DateTime _currentTime = new DateTime.now();

  Future<Null> selectTime(BuildContext context) async {
    DateTime seletedTime = await showTimePicker(context: context, initialTime: _currentTime);
  }
```

Is there any way to get the time in `12 hour clock time` something like this `10:00pm`.

any help would be great.

Comment: Check here https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html

Comment: @EsenMehmet I did go through that docs but the problem is when i put `_currentTime ` into showTimePicker `initialTime: _currentTime`  i get error.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use:

```
TimeOfDay _currentTime = TimeOfDay.now();
```

Because, looking at the https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showTimePicker.html, a `TimeOfDay` type is being used instead of `DateTime`.

You will need to change the call to the following to make everything work fine:

```
TimeOfDay selectedTime = await showTimePicker(context: context, initialTime: _currentTime);
```

> Is there any way to get the time in 12 hour clock time something like this 10:00pm.

For your second question, you can use `formatTimeOfDay` from the `MaterialLocalizations` class. See the following:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialLocalizations/formatTimeOfDay.html

And set `alwaysUse24HourFormat` to `false`.

```
MaterialLocalizations localizations = MaterialLocalizations.of(context);
String formattedTime = localizations.formatTimeOfDay(selectedTime, alwaysUse24HourFormat: false);
```

Comment: It says `timeOfDay` is undefined.

Comment: Yes, since that value does not exist. You should use `selectedTime` there. My bad.

Comment: One more thing How am I supposed to display time on screen earlier i was doing like this by updating state of `_currentTime` like this `setState(() {
          _currentTime = formattedTime;
        });`

Comment: but now it says this `Error: A value of type 'String' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'TimeOfDay'.`

Comment: You should post a new question on StackOverflow if you have a new question. Reading your questions, I would recommend you to learn the Dart and Flutter basics first. You should create a new `Text` widget and set the `formattedTime` to that `Text` widget.

Comment: kind of but the problem is I am unable to display the current time in that format. I want to make the current time to display when widget initialized and then update the state when the user selects a different time from the time picker.